# Does ActiveJob have queues with specific priority?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activejob

Looking at the job below I would assume the job runs on a `low_priority` queue.

```
class GuestsCleanupJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :low_priority
  #....
end
```

I would agree with this, but this is just the name of the queue correct? It actually has nothing to do with priority. For example if I created a job with a queue named `:my_queue` it would be treated as having the same priority as a `:low_priority` queue.

From the documentation I haven't been able to find anything indicating that I can prioritize jobs that are queued. I know delayed_jobs has this functionality, but I haven't found it in active_job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Priority depends on actual QueueAdapter and how this adapter was configured. If your adapter does not support priorities or was not properly configured, then ActiveJob can't help you either.

Find out more details about adapters from here:

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html

The main takeaway is this:

> The main point is to ensure that all Rails apps will have a job infrastructure in place. We can then have framework features and other gems build on top of that, without having to worry about API differences between various job runners such as Delayed Job and Resque. Picking your queuing backend becomes more of an operational concern, then. And you'll be able to switch between them without having to rewrite your jobs.

Queue configuration (including priorities) becomes Adapter's responsibility.

As an example of queue configuration see Sidekiq wiki:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues

Comment: Yes this makes sense, but delayed_job and sidekiq both support queues and priority and you can set this at a job level. Does active job support this if you are using the delayed_job or sidekiq adapter? It sounds like you are saying yes ... but none of the documentation actually helps. I have already looked at the references you have added before posting this question, but I couldn't find anything ... perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: You need to read your adapter documentation for this. ActiveJob is an abstraction.

Comment: I understand that. I have read the documentation - I am using delayed_jobs and you can set the priority of a job on a delayed_job for example `handle_asynchronously :send_mailer, :priority => 20`.With sidekiq I can see it's possible since you set queues and priority in a config file.Delayed job does not seem to have this. My question is how to I use the abstraction that is ActiveJob in order to set priority ... is this possible via ActiveJob or do I have to use delayed_job? Looking at the delayed_job adapter in ActiveJob this does not seem possible.I am not sure what else to say to be clearer.

Comment: You can't set priority through ActiveJob programatically. You just name you queues "low_priority" or "high_priority" and use them under these names in your program. Actually you have no control from your program whether "low" is really "low" and "high" is really "high" priority. They are just names. It's upon you to configure them with correct weights (priorities).

Comment: Great that is what I was trying to confirm. From what I see using activejob on top of delayed_job it is impossible to actually configure the weight correct? You can only set the default weight in the config. You can't actually set the weighting per job or queue if using activejob on top of delayed_job since there is not entry point via the abstraction that is activejob.

Comment: See purpose of ActiveJob from Rails guide (I've included it in answer). It clearly states this

Comment: Since this issue seems to be getting a couple of hits, for those that may be interested, I wrote some functionality and got it merged into DJ to actually handle queues with priority. This should work with ActiveJob with a DJ config file. https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/pull/845#issuecomment-178173963